# Multiple resolutions on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm moving to WP8.1 and there are different resolutions to be supported so I need to create the correct resources for each scaling factor.

Following [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965325.aspx) I've found out that I can use a simple naming conventions and the appropriate image will be automatically loaded without having to manage it from code.

What the guide doesn't say, and I can't seem to find it anywhere, is what the original size should be.

I need to know which one is the resolution that corresponds to the 100 scaling factor so that I can calculate the size of the scaled images.

Do you have any idea on this?

There's a **lot** of documentation for *Windows Store* (I'm not using *Silverlight*) apps but everything seems always related to desktop/tablets even if there's the phone icon.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? Or a proper doc for this?

Comment: Nope, I just given up and considered as 100 scaling factor the lowest resolution available

Comment: It will lead to blurring on high res devices. :(

Comment: Not really: consider the lowest resolution as 100 scaling factor and buil your resources for the highest scaling factor (which is 240) so that you'll have high res images. Then you can just downscale the 240 one to create the various 180, 140 and 100

Answer (score 1):

Please refer section "1.a.i" as guideline (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965325.aspx) mention by you. 
You need to create image with 96 DPI, considering as 100% scale.

I also recommended refer guidelines provided in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465362.aspx. Refer below statement from provided link.

> "Windows Runtime apps (that run on Windows, Windows Phone, or both)
>   are automatically scaled by the system to ensure consistent
>   readability and functionality regardless of a screen's pixel density."

And also below one.

> "Windows determines which scaling plateau to use based on the physical
>   screen size, the screen resolution, the DPI of the screen, and form
>   factor."

Hope this helps.