# Windows Universal App Device Size

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm currently developing a universal app, but when I deploy either the Windows version or the phone version, the layouts change because the resolutions differ.  If I create a separate phone-only project and copy it over the layout is fine.  How do set the device size for both the desktop and the phone versions?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808415/multiple-resolutions-on-windows-phone-8-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is vague, but [my presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-541) from the **//Build** conference might help. Basically the layout size depends on the screen's size, its DPI, and what the estimated viewing distance is.

The reason a Phone-only solutions works (assuming you chose a **Silverlight** project) is because for Silverlight apps, the OS always guarantees your app is 480 effective pixels wide (aka "view pixels" or "logical pixels"). This changed in Windows Phone 8.1 to better match the Windows Desktop behaviour due to the general increase in screen sizes. I provide some more background [in this blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/22/taking-advantage-of-large-screen-windows-phones/) which also shows how you can override Silverlight's default 480px width on large-screen phones.

If you really just want to have the same layout size on all devices and have the OS resize it to fit the screen, a [`Viewbox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox.aspx) is what you need, although it won't give the best experience. This is used in one of the demos in the presentation.